# C++ RSA Signing

Tags: c++, rsa, digital-signature

I am trying to sign some data with given RSA parameters.

I am given Modulus, Exponent, D, DP, DQ, P, Q, and InverseQ. What library or methods would be the easiest and simplest to use to compute this signature. In C#, they have a specific method for signing data once you give parameters. Again, I am looking for simplicity and possibly just a straight up header and cpp file if possible. Thanks.

Comment: openssl is an obvious choice.

Answer (score 2):

While I've never used it myself, the [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com) library should give you what you want.

Their wiki has an RSA signing example: http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Cryptography#RSA_Signature_Scheme_.28PKCS_v1.5.29

For signing, you should of course only need the private key.